# Users not able to sign in using Parse

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I'm using Parse.com and my app is supposed to let users sign up and login. They are able to sign up, at which point I see that they get stored on the Parse database, but when I try using the same username and password on my login activity, it says it does not exist. After the user signs up though, it goes into the MainActivity, up until you sign out, then you can't log back in. Any help?

Here is my SignUp Activity

```
public class SignupActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
EditText mName, mUsername, mEmail, mPassword, mPasswordConfirm;
Button mSignup, mCancel;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);

    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    mName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    mUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    mEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    mPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    mPasswordConfirm = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.confirm_password);
    mSignup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signup_button);



    mSignup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final String username = mUsername.getText().toString().trim();
            final String email = mEmail.getText().toString().trim();
            final String password = mPassword.getText().toString().trim();
            final String confirmedPassword = mPasswordConfirm.getText().toString().trim();
            final String name = mName.getText().toString().trim();



            if(username.isEmpty() || email.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty()){
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SignupActivity.this);
                builder.setMessage("Item missing in Signup Fields")
                    .setPositiveButton("Ok", null)
                    .setTitle("Error Message");
                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();                  
            }
            else if(!confirmPass(password, confirmedPassword)){
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SignupActivity.this);
                builder.setMessage("Passwords do not match")
                    .setPositiveButton("Ok", null)
                    .setTitle("Error Message");
                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();
            }
            else{                   
                ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
                user.setUsername(username);
                user.setPassword(password);
                user.setEmail(email);
                user.put("Name", name);

                setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
                user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        setProgressBarIndeterminate(false);
                        if(e == null){
                            Intent intent = new Intent(SignupActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                            startActivity(intent);

                        }
                        else{
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SignupActivity.this);
                            builder.setMessage(e.getMessage())
                                .setTitle("Error Message")
                                .setPositiveButton("Ok", null);
                            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                            dialog.show();
                        }

                    }
                });
            }

        }
    });


}
public boolean confirmPass(String password, String passwordConfirm){
    if(password.equals(passwordConfirm)){
        return true;
    }
    else return false;
}


}
```

Here is my LoginActivity
    public class LoginActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

```
EditText mUsername, mPassword;
Button mLogin;
TextView mSignup;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Allows us to use progress circle
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    //hides action bar
    getActionBar().hide();

    mUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    mPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    mLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sign_in);
    mSignup = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sign_up);

    //goes to signup page when clicked
    mSignup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SignupActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

    //logs user in when clicked
    mLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        String username = mUsername.getText().toString().trim();
        String password = mPassword.getText().toString().trim();

        //checks to make sure user exists or doesn't exist to sign them in
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ParseUser.logInInBackground(username, password, new LogInCallback() {

                //if user exists, do this
                @Override
                public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
                    if(e == null){
                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, (CharSequence) user, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        //makes sure you can't press "back" in the next activity and come back to Login page
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    //if user doesn't exist, show error message
                    else{
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
                        builder.setMessage((CharSequence) username)
                        .setPositiveButton("Ok", null)
                        .setTitle("Error Message");
                        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                        dialog.show();
                    }

                }
            });

        }
    });

}



}
```

Here is my MainActivity
    public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

```
ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> mainAdapter;
CustomAdapter customAdapter;
ListView listView;
TextView ideaTitle;
ImageView icon;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ideaTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
    icon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon);



    ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();


    if(currentUser == null){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }else {
        Log.i("USERNAME", currentUser.getUsername());

         customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this);             
          listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
          listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);             
    }       
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();



}

 @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    //get selected items
     System.out.println(l);
     System.out.println(v);
     System.out.println(position);
     System.out.println(id);

     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, (int) position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch(id){

    case R.id.add_idea:
        Intent add = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddIdeaActivity.class);
        startActivity(add);
        break;

    case R.id.logout:
        ParseUser.logOut();
        Intent logout = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        logout.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        logout.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(logout);
        break;

    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your login use the same parse init  session as main activity.

Create new user in your app.

Verify parse dashboard shows the new entry in User table.

Use curl to log on to your app  from terminal session ( cmd) if on windows os.

If u can curl cli   log on following log on instruction in parse rest Api docs, then u know u r log on activity has bug.